# How can I read the metadata of a type at runtime?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to write a program that prints out some metadata of a Haskell type. Although I know this isn't valid code, the idea is something like:

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }

metadata :: Type -> String
metadata t = ???

metadata Person -- returns "Person (name,age)"
```

The important restriction being I don't have an instance of `Person`, just the type.

I've started looking into Generics & Typeable/Data, but without an instance I'm not sure they'll do what I need. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reflection in Haskell works using the `Typeable` class, which is defined in [`Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Typeable.html) and includes the `typeOf`* method to get a run-time representation of a value's type.

```
ghci> :m +Data.Typeable
ghci> :t typeOf 'a'
typeOf 'a' :: TypeRep
ghci> typeOf 'a'  -- We could use any value of type Char and get the same result
Char  -- the `Show` instance of `TypeRep` just returns the name of the type
```

If you want `Typeable` to work for your own types, you can have the compiler generate an instance for you with the `DeriveDataTypeable` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving Typeable
```

<s>You can also write your own instance, but really, no one has the time for that.</s> <sub>Apparently you can't - see the comments</sub>

You can now use `typeOf` to grab a run-time representation of your type. We can query information about the type constructor (abbreviated to `TyCon`) and its type arguments:

```
-- (undefined :: Person) stands for "some value of type Person".
-- If you have a real Person you can use that too.
-- typeOf does not use the value, only the type
-- (which is known at compile-time; typeOf is dispatched using the normal instance selection rules)
ghci> typeOf (undefined :: Person)
Person
ghci> tyConName $ typeRepTyCon $ typeOf (undefined :: Person)
"Person"
ghci> tyConModule $ typeRepTyCon $ typeOf (undefined :: Person)
"Main"
```

`Data.Typeable` also provides a *type-safe cast* operation which allows you to branch on a value's runtime type, somewhat like C#'s `as` operator.

```
f :: Typeable a => a -> String
f x = case (cast x :: Maybe Int) of
           Just i -> "I can treat i as an int in this branch " ++ show (i * i)
           Nothing -> case (cast x :: Maybe Bool) of
                           Just b -> "I can treat b as a bool in this branch " ++ if b then "yes" else "no"
                           Nothing -> "x was of some type other than Int or Bool"

ghci> f True
"I can treat b as a bool in this branch yes"
ghci> f (3 :: Int)
"I can treat i as an int in this branch 9"
```

Incidentally, a nicer way to write `f` is to use a GADT enumerating the set of types you expect your function to be called with. This allows us to lose the `Maybe` (`f` can never fail!), does a better job of documenting our assumptions, and gives compile-time feedback when we need to change the set of admissible argument types for `f`. (You can write a class to make `Admissible` implicit if you like.)

```
data Admissible a where
    AdInt :: Admissible Int
    AdBool :: Admissible Bool
f :: Admissible a -> a -> String
f AdInt i = "I can treat i as an int in this branch " ++ show (i * i)
f AdBool b = "I can treat b as a bool in this branch " ++ if b then "yes" else "no"
```

In reality I probably wouldn't do either of these - I'd just stick `f` in a class and define instances for `Int` and `Bool`.

---

If you want run-time information about the right-hand side of a type definition, you need to use the entertainingly-named [`Data.Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Data.html), which defines a subclass of `Typeable` called `Data`.** GHC can derive `Data` for you too, with the same extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

Now we can grab a run-time representation of the *values* of a type, not just the type itself:

```
ghci> dataTypeOf (undefined :: Person)
DataType {tycon = "Main.Person", datarep = AlgRep [Person]}
ghci> dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf (undefined :: Person)
[Person]  -- Person only defines one constructor, called Person
ghci> constrFields $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf (undefined :: Person)
["name","age"]
```

---

`Data.Data` is the API for generic programming; if you ever hear people talking about ["Scrap Your Boilerplate"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/hmap/hmap.ps), this (along with [`Data.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.4.4/docs/Data-Generics.html), which builds on `Data.Data`) is what they mean. For example, you can write a function which converts record types to JSON using reflection on the type's fields.

```
toJSON :: Data a => a -> String
-- Implementation omitted because it is boring.
-- But you only have to write the boring code once,
-- and it'll be able to serialise any instance of `Data`.
-- It's a good exercise to try to write this function yourself!
```

<sub>* In recent versions of GHC, this API has changed somewhat. Consult the docs.</sub>

<sub>** Yes, the fully-qualified name of that class is `Data.Data.Data`.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the excellent explanation. That `(undefined :: Person)` trick was particularly enlightening. I hadn't realised there was a way to get an 'empty' instance of the type. :-)

Comment: It works because `typeOf` doesn't actually use the value of its argument. We just need to give it 'something' of a certain type so that GHC can select the right instance of `Typeable`.

Comment: @KrisJenkins There's a lot of contention about the `undefined` trick.  Some people think it's sufficient, others think that it's a hack since it uses `undefined`.  You could implement the API to instead use something like `typeOf :: Typeable a => Proxy a -> TypeRep` and `typeOf (Proxy :: Proxy Person)` which avoids `undefined`, but then there's disagreement on exactly how this should be implemented too.  For most use cases `undefined` should work well, but avoid using the actual value for anything since it'll raise an exception.

Comment: Defining your own `Typeable` instance is not just a waste of time; it's also extremely unsafe. It's prohibited in Safe Haskell, and it will most likely be prohibited altogether sometime soon. See Simon Peyton Jones's recent [comment](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9858#comment:20) to that effect.

Comment: @dfeuer Actually it is *already* generally prohibited. The comment is talking about how GHC generates actual "source code" for the instances internally when deriving them, and suggesting to change that into a more efficient approach. (Of course thanks to the bug discussed, some uses of `Typeable` are currently extremely unsafe anyway.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, ah, I didn't realize that. I guess the code I've seen doing it manually was just for pre-7.8 GHC. I probably even noticed that at some point, and forgot.

Comment: @bheklilr, what's complicated about implementing such an interface?

Comment: An alternative to using `undefined` or `Proxy` is to add a phantom type to the `TypeRep` itself, turning it into `TTypeRep a`. There is actually [a proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Typeable) to do this, for more typesafe composition of `Typeable/Dynamic` values, useful for distributed Haskell.