# freer-simple - How can I generate a list of effect members at runtime?

Tags: haskell, reflection

I am trying to create a function to generate a string representation of effects at runtime.

-- In a shared module

```
... definitions for TestConfig, RunConfig

data GenericTest tc rc i effs as vs = GenericTest {
  configuration :: tc,
  components :: ItemClass i vs => TestComponents rc i effs as vs
} deriving Typeable

type Test = GenericTest TestConfig RunConfig

type EFFLogger effs = Member Logger effs
type EFFFileSystem effs = Members '[Logger, Ensure, FileSystem] effs
```

-- Child module 1

```
.... definitions for items, iterator etc 

type Effects effs = EFFFileSystem effs

test :: forall effs. Effects effs => Test Item effs ApState ValState
test = GenericTest {
              configuration = config {address = moduleOf ''ApState},
              components = TestComponents {
                                testItems = items,
                                testInteractor = interactor,
                                testPrepState = prepState
                            }
            }
```

-- Child module 2 (the same as module 1 but different effects)

```
.... definitions for items, iterator etc 

type Effects effs = EFFLogger effs

test :: forall effs. Effects effs => Test Item effs ApState ValState
test = GenericTest {
              configuration = config {address = moduleOf ''ApState},
              components = TestComponents {
                                testItems = items,
                                testInteractor = interactor,
                                testPrepState = prepState
                            }
            }
```

At run time I want a function `f` such that:

```
> f ChildMod1.test 
> ["Logger", "Ensure", "FileSystem"]
>
> f ChildMod2.test 
>  ["Logger"]
```

From repl with Child module 1 loaded I can get the following, which if I could get something similar in non-interpreted code would be enough to get me what I want:

```
> :t test
> test
    :: (Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem Logger effs,
        Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem Ensure effs,
        Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem FileSystem effs) =>
       Test Item effs ApState ValState
```

I have tried using Typeable as suggested in the following:

[How can I read the metadata of a type at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243383/how-can-i-read-the-metadata-of-a-type-at-runtime)

but typeOf gives me issues which I have no clue how to solve:

```
> typeOf test

  <interactive>:5:1-11: error:
      * No instance for (Typeable effs0) arising from a use of `typeOf'
      * In the expression: typeOf test
        In an equation for `it': it = typeOf test

  <interactive>:5:8-11: error:
      * Ambiguous type variable `effs0' arising from a use of `test'
        prevents the constraint `(Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem
                                    Logger effs0)' from being solved.
        Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `effs0' should be.
        These potential instances exist:
          two instances involving out-of-scope types
            instance [overlappable] Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem t r =>
                                    Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem t (t' : r)
              -- Defined in `Data.OpenUnion.Internal'
            instance Data.OpenUnion.Internal.FindElem t (t : r)
              -- Defined in `Data.OpenUnion.Internal'
      * In the first argument of `typeOf', namely `test'
        In the expression: typeOf test
        In an equation for `it': it = typeOf test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, given a (type-level) list of effects `effs`, we can obtain a string of it via `Typeable`:

```
import Type.Reflection

showEffs :: forall effs. Typeable effs => String
showEffs = show (typeRep @effs)
```

Now the problem is for a function `f` to grab the constraint in the type of its argument. As you have witnessed, a naive attempt will fail: `f test` will specialize `test` and propagate the constraints upwards, resulting in errors about instance resolution and ambiguous type variables.

A better solution is to replace `=>` with a regular data type, which is "matchable".

```
newtype WithEffects_ es0 es1 a = WithEffects { unWithEffects :: Members es0 es1 => a }
```

The type synonyms also need some refactoring.

```
type EFileSystem = '[Logger, Ensure, FileSystem]
type WithEffects = WithEffects_ EFileSystem
```

Now a test looks like this:

```
test :: forall effs. WithEffects effs (Test Item effs ApState ValState)
test = WithEffects $ ... -- the rest unchanged
```

and you'll need to unwrap it explicitly with `unWithEffects test`. We can now extract a runtime representation of the effects `es0` from `WithEffects_ es0 es1 a`:

```
import Type.Reflection

effsRepTest :: Typeable es0 => WithEffects_ es0 es1 a -> TypeRep es
effsRepTest _ = typeRep

showEffsTest :: Typeable es0 => WithEffects_ es0 es1 a -> String
showEffsTest = show . effsRepTest
```

So, to extract a string representing `es0`, we can write:

```
showEffsTest test :: String
```

---

EDITED: you may find traces of an old version of this answer in the comments, which proposed to use `newtype c ==> a = Arr { unArr :: c => a }`, but that doesn't work here as `Members` is a type family. So you need another type that carries the list of effects more explicitly `es0` like `WithEffects_`.

---

EDITED, again:

Here is a minimal compilable gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/d7b6bdc23bcb43cb40439b7e037e8145

The above answer actually prints this:

```
': (* -> *) Logger (': (* -> *) Ensure (': (* -> *) FileSystem ('[] (* -> *))))
```

For a better looking result, I implemented a custom printer in that gist (the `ShowTypes` class).

Comment: Think I missing something here.

I assume the caveat doesn't apply in my case as the only constraint on test in my case is on effs. 

I have tried to apply the this solution in one of the child modules as follows:

Comment: Try putting your code and error messages (if any) on gist.github.com or some other pastebin.

Comment: OK doing it now

Comment: gist summarising issues I am having compiling this: https://gist.github.com/theGhostJW/2b751dba4323fd5100fad711b9821bc0

Comment: Oh I see, `Members` is a type family, so `Members es0 e0 ~ Members es1 e1` does not imply `es0 ~ es1`, and I was relying on that implication... So I think the next simplest way is to change `==>` to a different type that directly exposes the effects list. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Still have issues. SO has suggested a move to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183529/discussion-between-john-walker-and-li-yao-xia